# What is the significance of the version byte in front of RIPEMD-160 hash?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, public-key

Public Address is generated from the private key following some steps. Please refer [Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address) to see the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version byte is used to differentiate between MainNet and TestNet addresses as well as between P2PKH and P2SH addresses.

Comment: Can you tell me the version byte of MainNet and TestNet addresses?

Comment: @idk it is `0x00` for mainnet and `0x6f` for testnet. You can find all the prefixes here : https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes